# VS Cordova projects won;t debug on IOS device

Tags: ios, visual-studio, deployment, taco

All:

Trying to find a substitute for Telerik Platform (discontinued) to produce Cordova based apps.  Have tried using Visual Studio w/ TACO toolkit installed in both VS 2017 and VS2015.   What a disaster of things that don't work.  Lot's of moving parts that can easily get screwed up by Windows updates VS updates etc. , hacked tools etc etc.

Have been able to build and deploy (blankcordovaapp) to device with Xcode (after submitting project from VS) but the whole goal of this was to be able to debug with VS and make programmer's job easier.

I can get system to build and load build back to PC but from there it just never loads up on a physical device (yes I have the provisioning correct).

Comes up with errors like "can't find app on device".  Of course I can have programmers use Browser based emulators to develop, and ultimately debug and deploy through Xcode (just what I wanted these guys to learn !!!) but I guess I'm still drinking the MS kool-aid.

Question is:  "Does anyone actually have this working !!!!".  If so, could you share setup, versions, hacks etc.  I see an awful lot of people on SO who never get answers to similar questions.

Though I'd give this a try

Regards

BF

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a working combination?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

We have been able to send VS2017 Cordova apps to Mac and compile through Xcode (9.2) and have the application returned to the PC and deployed to an IOS device connected to that PC.  This took a LOT of reading and screwing around with libimobile install  (let me know if you want the setup).  IOS 11.x and libimobile versions seem to be the issue in this setup, but we got it working.  Let me know if you need a detailed approach.  Would be happy to share it with you.

As far as debugging right from VS 2017 on the device, I don't think that's ever going to (or ever did) happen.   Have spent a lot of time on this with no positive results.

The **good thing** is that we discovered that we can debug Cordova based webkit sites (and safari sites) on the device (IOS) using Chrome tools on the (remote) PC using remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter.  This seems to work pretty well. We also tried VS Code with this with no  real positive results for debugging on the device.

I really don't think MS cares much about this approach.  They push the hell out of this on websites etc.,, but really don't provide any real support.  I'm planning on presenting this to some MS contacts and get their take on this.

The main issue is that it seems to be all of the open source support stuff that is messed up.  I like open source as a concept, but when I have to deliver to a customer I need REAL support for things that don't work as opposed to I'll get to this whenever  (and an attitude to boot) !!!.

Anyway let me know if you need help with this and I'll document what we have done so far.

Bill

Comment: Yes, Microsoft was doing a lot on this platform, UNTIL they bought Xamarin.  Now, Taco and Cordova is completely forgotten, they don't even remember to get rid of the web pages.

I'm still using Cordova, but now using VS Code on Mac and doing iOS and Android testing/development there.  Not quite as good or promising as using VS2017, but it does work.  And it also adds a platform because I can now add macOS version of app as well.